# Copy Matrix Value to a New Matrix Efficiently

Tags: c#, matrix

Is there an efficient built in method that copies the value from one matrix (e.g., `double[,]`) to another?

In order words, I'm looking for a replacement of the below function:

```
    public static double[,]CloneMatrix(double[,] aMatrix)
    {
        var newMatrix = new double[aMatrix.GetLength(0),aMatrix.GetLength(1)];
        for (int i = 0; i < aMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < aMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                newMatrix[i, j] = aMatrix[i, j];
            }
        }
        return newMatrix;

    }
```

Comment: @Mark, question updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Clone method:

```
double[,] result = (double[,])aMatrix.Clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional arrays are themselves slower than vectors (what we call "single-dimensional" arrays, which are in fact a little different from vectors) because of how they are implemented (with different bounds checking and access rules). So, as a side note, you might want to consider using a `double[][]` in some cases, if efficiency is a concern.